# Samba is removed from Lion. How is the role of auto_master changed

Tags: sharing, macos, smb

I used to use the /etc/auto_master file to load SMB shares in Snow leopard Mac OS X

Now that Samba is removed, I wonder what should be the correct way to auto mount windows shares.

Comment: Let's wait until it's officially released before asking people to break their word about NDA publicly here. The apple developer forums are a better place to talk about pre-release software.

Comment: Questions about pre-release software is off-topic per the FAQ.

Comment: reopen them, dude. they are released software :D

Answer (score 2):

Mac OS X never used Samba's SMB client. Mac OS X has always used an SMB client implementation based on Boris Popov's `smbfs` for FreeBSD. I don't think that's changing in Lion, so its relation to /etc/auto_master probably isn't changing.

As for the SMB server side, Samba is surely being replaced with a different SMB server software package.

Comment: It seems to me that the entire setup is better in Lion, but I am still unsure of what the best practise is to map windows shares to Lion.